# Polymer application with OpenShift

Tags: polymer, openshift

How can I configure a Polymer application to work with Open Shift cloud?

There is an example for a start up script?

Comment: What is a Polymer application? Can you provide a link to documentation about it? What version of OpenShift are you talking about. Old V2, or newer V3 based on Kubernetes and Docker?

Comment: Is about this framework: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/. I was wondering if there is already one cartridge on open shift already configured to work with this. I think I will make it myself.